# Calc period of function in R

Tags: r, function, period

There is any R packages for calculation period of some function? I am looking for r-function like this:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, by = 0.05)
y <- sin(x)
p <- calcPeriod(x, y) # result = 2pi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of a Fast Fourier Transform. I'm no expert, but I think you can do something along the lines of the following:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, by = 0.05)
y <- sin(x)

calcPeriod <- function(x, y){
    incr <- x[2] - x[1]
    tmp <- spectrum(y, plot=FALSE)
    p <- (1/tmp$freq*incr)[which.max(tmp$spec)] # max of spectrum
    p
}

calcPeriod(x,y) # equals 6.4
```

The function `spectrum`is actually a wrapper function for `spec.pgram` and `spec.ar`. Use with caution since the `calcPeriod`function is actually only identifying the maximum periodicity. For unevenly sampled series, a least-squares specrtal analysis would also identify the dominant periodicity ([example link](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2013/01/lomb-scargle-periodogram-for-unevenly.html)).

Comment: Minor nit: the function is a "Fourier Transform"; an FFT is just one algorithmic implementation of a Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 1):

Paul H.'s answer reminded me that, if you prefer not to deal with Fourier analysis, you could always run `nls(y~sin(k*x))`   or an enhanced version thereof.  This does assume you know in advance there's only one frequency in your data.

I'll put my usual plug here for `Eureqa` , easily found at Cornell.edu via Google.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a function myself, but you could use `optim` to optimize a cost function which takes the period as a parameter. `optim` would then tweak the period until an optimal fit was acquired. This is not very hard to do, and you can wrap this into a function `calcPeriod` yourself.

Comment: That's kinda going about it the hard way :-).

Comment: But if it is hard, the challenge is greater, and thus the satisfaction ;).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: should we assume that you also push your car to work? ;-)